# Clipping path point animation on scroll not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am currently working on a project where the background of the site has 3 masked images, and when the user scrolls, the points of these images move with the scroll. I can get it working well in Chrome, but just can't get it to play nice with any other browser. Due to time constraints, I am currently only required to get this working in Safari and Chrome (other browsers get served a static image).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/wickywills/pen/GQzaXE)

If you scroll in Chrome, you should see the desired effect. I have read elsewhere about how Safari has many issues with SVG's and that I should use an Object tag instead, however I am unsure how I can apply the Object tag given that I need the points inline so that I can change them via JS, or am I missing something?

**HTML**

```
<div id="site-wrap" class="c-site c-images">
  <img id="nodes-bg-3i-1" width="100%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1500x2800">
  <img id="nodes-bg-3i-2" width="100%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1500x2800">
  <img id="nodes-bg-3i-3" width="100%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1500x2800">
  <svg id="nodes-mask-desk" width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clipPolygon" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <polygon id="poly1" points="0.35 0.23,1 0.28,1 0,0.6 0">
        </polygon>
      </clipPath>
      <clipPath id="clipPolygon2" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <polygon id="poly2" points="0.0 0.26,0.35 0.23,0.6 0.62,0.0 0.62">
        </polygon>
      </clipPath>
      <clipPath id="clipPolygon3" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <polygon id="poly3" points="0.3 1,1 1,1 0.62,0.6 0.62">
        </polygon>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

**CSS (SCSS)**

```
#nodes-bg-3i-1 { -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipPolygon); clip-path: url(#clipPolygon); }
#nodes-bg-3i-2 { -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipPolygon2); clip-path: url(#clipPolygon2); }
#nodes-bg-3i-3 { -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipPolygon3); clip-path: url(#clipPolygon3); }

#mob-img-1 { -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipMob1); clip-path: url(#clipMob1); }
#mob-img-2 { -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipMob2); clip-path: url(#clipMob2); }
#mob-img-3 { -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipMob3); clip-path: url(#clipMob3); }

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;

  &:nth-child(2),
  &:nth-child(3){
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
var animPoints = {

  init: function() {
    var isScrolling;
    var scrollingDone = false;

    animPoints.pointParallaxBackgrounds();

    // Init backgrounds on scroll, but wait for a period of time after scroll starts before init
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {
      animPoints.pointParallaxBackgrounds();
    }, false);
  },

  pointParallaxBackgrounds: function(){
    var el = document.getElementById('site-wrap');
    var scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

    var poly1 = document.getElementById("poly1"); // Points element within SVG
    var poly1Points = poly1.getAttribute("points"); // Points attribute containing position values
    var poly1PointsArr = poly1Points.split(","); // We only need the fourth point's coordinates
    var poly1PointPair1Arr = poly1PointsArr[3].split(" "); // We only need the first point's coordinates

    var poly2 = document.getElementById("poly2"); // Points element within SVG
    var poly2Points = poly2.getAttribute("points"); // Points attribute containing position values
    var poly2PointsArr = poly2Points.split(","); // We only need the second point's coordinates
    var poly2PointPair2Arr = poly2PointsArr[1].split(" "); // We only need the first point's coordinates
    var poly2PointPair3Arr = poly2PointsArr[2].split(" "); // We only need the first point's coordinates


    var poly3 = document.getElementById("poly3"); // Points element within SVG
    var poly3Points = poly3.getAttribute("points"); // Points attribute containing position values
    var poly3PointsArr = poly3Points.split(","); // We only need the fourth point's coordinates
    var poly3PointPair4Arr = poly3PointsArr[3].split(" "); // We only need the fourth point's coordinates

    // Update polygon 2 Y axis
    poly2PointPair2Arr[1] = (0.2 + (scrollPos * .4)  / el.offsetHeight);
    poly1PointPair1Arr[1] = poly2PointPair2Arr[1];
    poly1PointPair1Arr[0] = poly2PointPair2Arr[0];
    poly2PointPair3Arr[1] = (0.4 + (scrollPos * .4)  / el.offsetHeight);
    poly3PointPair4Arr[1] = poly2PointPair3Arr[1];


    // Set some boundss
    if(poly2PointPair2Arr[1] <= 0.23){
      poly2PointPair2Arr[1] = 0.23;
      poly1PointPair1Arr[1] = 0.23;
    }


    if(poly2PointPair3Arr[1] <= 0.61){
      poly2PointPair3Arr[1] = 0.61;
      poly3PointPair4Arr[1] = 0.61;
    }

    // Convert modified array of points back to string, and update var
    poly1PointsArr[0] = poly1PointPair1Arr.join(" ");
    poly2PointsArr[1] = poly2PointPair2Arr.join(" ");
    poly2PointsArr[2] = poly2PointPair3Arr.join(" ");
    poly3PointsArr[3] = poly3PointPair4Arr.join(" ");


    poly1.setAttribute('points', poly1PointsArr);
    poly2.setAttribute('points', poly2PointsArr);
    poly3.setAttribute('points', poly3PointsArr);
  }
};

var chrome   = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1;
var explorer = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > -1;
var firefox  = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1;
var safari   = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;

if(chrome || safari) {
  console.log("test");
  animPoints.init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I noticed that on browser resize, after scrolling in Safari, the points updated. I therefore found that triggering either a browser resize or resetting `offsetWidth` on scroll for the images with the clipping path did the trick! So basically:

```
var img1 = document.getElementById("nodes-bg-3i-1");
img1.style.clipPath = "none";
img1.offsetWidth;
img1.style.clipPath = "url(#clipPolygon)";
```

Appling that to each image within `pointParallaxBackgrounds` worked!